# compareTo() How to use three words instead of two

Tags: java

Is there a way to use compareTo() to use three words instead of two

such as a1.compareTo(a2); which uses two, how do you use three?

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no such method and anyway, the results of a tree-way comparison cannot be meaningfully expressed with a single integer quantity.

If you think you need such a method, what you really need is a way to **sort** three items. Put them into an array, or a `List`, and call `Arrays.sort` or `Collections.sort`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Use a collection just like this:

```
    String n = "word";      
    Collection<String> f = new ArrayList<String>();
    f.add("one");
    f.add("one");
    f.add("one");
    System.out.println(Collections.frequency(f, "one") == f.size());
    f.add("tow");
    System.out.println(Collections.frequency(f, "one") == f.size());
```